# SQL Query Help, Need some expert opinions

Tags: sql

I have this query and it works well, the question is if there is a way to have the query NULL the column value if it doesn't exist in the table?

```
UPDATE PRD_WOCNT 
SET c1 = (
  SELECT WO_CNT.RATE FROM WO_CNT
  WHERE WO_CNT.CNT = PRD_WOCNT.c1
) 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT WO_CNT.CNT FROM WO_CNT
  WHERE WO_CNT.CNT = PRD_WOCNT.c1
)
```

Right it uses a second table to update the main table values of sales codes into their commission rates. but sometimes a sales code is entered that doesn't exist in the table so it adds the sales code as a dollar value and makes the added total wrong.

I don't know too much PHP and trying not to bother with it if I can simply alter the query... it's a stab in the dark, have a feeling I'll need to do this on the PHP side but have no idea how I can have my query tell the php it doesn't exist.

Comment: The example is incomplete. Please provide sample table schema (as a `CREATE TABLE` statement), sample data (as an `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` statement) and desired results.

Comment: And name your database system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't executed. I think it will work. Try this query:

```
UPDATE PRD_WOCNT SET c1 = CASE
       WHEN EXISTS (
  SELECT WO_CNT.CNT FROM WO_CNT
  WHERE WO_CNT.CNT = PRD_WOCNT.c1
)
 THEN (
  SELECT WO_CNT.RATE FROM WO_CNT
  WHERE WO_CNT.CNT = PRD_WOCNT.c1
) 
       ELSE NULL
       END
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE a
SET c1 = WO_CNT.RATE
FROM PRD_WOCNT a
LEFT JOIN WO_CNT b
ON b.CNT = a.c1
```